# Component of the velocity gradient part of Vlasov equation in cylindrical coordinate

Tags: vector-fields, plasma-physics, kinetic-theory

I am stuck with a problem in expanding the velocity gradient part of the Vlasov equation in cylindrical basis. It is also applicable to the spatial gradient part as well. For example here I consider only the velocity gradient part, which could be written as,

$$\vec{A}(\vec{r},\vec{v},t).\nabla_{v}f$$

where, $A=(\vec{E}+\vec{v}\times\vec{B})$, with $\vec{E}$ is the electric field, $\vec{v}$ is the velocity, $\vec{B}$ is the magnetic field and $f$ is the distribution function. A naïve expansion of this term in cylindrical coordinate gives (see for [reference](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3798793/what-is-a-vector-dot-del-in-cylindrical-coordinates-vecu-cdot-nabla)),

$$\vec{A}(\vec{r},\vec{v},t).\nabla_{v}f=A_{\perp}\frac{\partial f}{\partial v_{\perp}}+\frac{A_{\phi}}{v_{\perp}}\frac{\partial f}{\partial \phi}+A_{||}\frac{\partial f}{\partial v_{||}}$$

Also it is known that for Vlasov equation $\vec{A}$ can be taken inside the velocity gradient making it a divergence equation as,

$$A(\vec{r},\vec{v},t).\nabla_{v}f=\nabla_{v}.(\vec{A}f)$$

whose expansion in cylindrical coordinate gives (see for [reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates)),

$$A(\vec{r},\vec{v},t).\nabla_{v}f=\nabla_{v}.(\vec{A}f)=\frac{1}{v_{\perp}}\frac{\partial (v_{\perp}A_{\perp}f)}{\partial v_{\perp}}+\frac{1}{v_{\perp}}\frac{\partial (A_{\phi}f)}{\partial \phi}+\frac{\partial (A_{||}f)}{\partial v_{||}}$$

Now these two expansion are same. So,

$$A_{\perp}\frac{\partial f}{\partial v_{\perp}}+\frac{A_{\phi}}{v_{\perp}}\frac{\partial f}{\partial \phi}+A_{||}\frac{\partial f}{\partial v_{||}}=\frac{1}{v_{\perp}}\frac{\partial (v_{\perp}A_{\perp}f)}{\partial v_{\perp}}+\frac{1}{v_{\perp}}\frac{\partial (A_{\phi}f)}{\partial \phi}+\frac{\partial (A_{||}f)}{\partial v_{||}}$$

The last term from both the sides are equal as $\vec{E}$ does not depends on $\vec{v}$ and $(\vec{v}\times\vec{B})_{||}$ will not depend on $v_{||}$. But for the second term in right hand side we have,

$$\frac{1}{v_{\perp}}\frac{\partial (A_{\phi}f)}{\partial \phi}=\frac{A_{\phi}}{v_{\perp}}\frac{\partial f}{\partial \phi}+\frac{f}{v_{\perp}}\frac{\partial A_{\phi}}{\partial \phi}$$

where the first term resembles with the second term of the left hand side of the above equation. But the next term in $\frac{1}{v_{\perp}}\frac{\partial (A_{\phi}f)}{\partial \phi}$ is a problem.

Now with the first term in the right hand side of the equation,

$$\frac{1}{v_{\perp}}\frac{\partial (v_{\perp}A_{\perp}f)}{\partial v_{\perp}}=A_{\perp}\frac{\partial f}{\partial v_{\perp}}+f\frac{\partial A_{\perp}}{\partial v_{\perp}}+\frac{A_{\perp}f}{v_{\perp}}$$

So my question is, whether $f\frac{\partial A_{\perp}}{\partial v_{\perp}}+\frac{A_{\perp}f}{v_{\perp}}+\frac{f}{v_{\perp}}\frac{\partial A_{\phi}}{\partial \phi}=0$?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Could you comment on why $A$ did go inside the divergence

Comment: Sure. It is a property of Lorentz Force. The x component of the force does not depend on x velocity and so on. That's why one can take the force inside the divergence.

Comment: Correct me if Im wrong but since the $\nabla _u $ refers to the velocity parts of the phase space, how you let appear of the term $\partial _\phi$ ? I think it should be $\partial _ {u_\phi}$ which would result in that equation being trivially satisfied

Comment: Yes. $\partial_{\phi}$ is same as $\partial_{u_{\phi}}$. But I am no clear how the equation is getting satisfied.